# Camerax produces different images than android's cam app and OpenCamera

Tags: android-camerax

I am using Camerax to capture 4032x3024 images but getting different results than other apps like open camera or android's camera app (different scale ? different fov?).

See that attached android's app
[image]

and the camerax:

[image]

Both apps use the back camera and same resolution.

Here is my code to bind to camera

```
 private void bindCamera(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider, CameraSelector cameraSelector, Size captureResolution, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer imageAnalyzer) {
        var imageAnalysisBuilder = new ImageAnalysis.Builder();
        var imageAnalysis = imageAnalysisBuilder.setImageQueueDepth(1)
                .setTargetResolution(captureResolution)
                .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build();
        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(analyzerExecutor, imageAnalyzer);
        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        if (lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().getCurrentState() != DESTROYED) {
            this.camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis);
        }
    }
```

How can I init cameraX differently ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Seems that in pixel 6 pro, video stabilization is enabled by default in CameraX, which results in cropping and smaller FOV (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230013960?pli=1)

So to fix this I do the following before binding the use case:

```
new Camera2Interop.Extender<>(myUseCase)
.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE,CameraMetadata.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF);
```